# Uncaught TypeError: Object local.process has no method 'call'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, to try to give you enough information to understand the scenario without pasting hundreds of lines of code here is a brief summary of what I have going on.

I am using data attributes to bind actions to different methods to different types of events using an unobtrusive style with data-attributes. These are all parsed and bound at document ready. Below is an example of an action that I would like to have happen based on the event specified. As you will see the attributes are pluralized because you can put a comma separated list of values, and the library will split them into arrays and bind each one accordingly. (You can have multiple actions run on a single "Click" event).

```
//An example button
<button data-perform-events="click" 
    data-perform-actions="local.process"></button>    

//The method used to parse the actions
getActions: function (submit) {
    return submit.attr('data-perform-actions').split(',');
}

//The method used to bind the action to the event
bindLocal: function (item, q, i) {
    item.object.on(item.events[q], { model: item, q: q }, function (event) {
        event.data.model.actions[event.data.q].call(this);
    });
}

//The action to be triggered
var local = {
    process: function (request) {
        alert("Called");
    }
}
```

Everything is being setup correctly, and the event fires correctly... The only problem is that I am hitting the following error, which I suspect has to do with the way that it is bound (a string from a data-attribute, not a direct assignment in JS code)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object local.process has no method 'call'
```

Any thoughts? How do I correct this?

Comment: This seems overly complicated, and a lot harder then just regular event handlers?

Comment: It is due to the library that I am creating... Allowing users to place multiple actions in data attributes and have them be called on events automatically by parsing the page on load. Very similar to the unobtrusive-validation library, but obviously not for validations...

Comment: This approach seems to require that all your event handler functions be in the global scope, which most would consider a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
event.data.model.actions[event.data.q]
```

will be returning "local.process" which is a string

now string cannot have call method

hence you should try

```
var local = event.data.model.actions[event.data.q];
var arr = local.split(".")
window[arr[0]][arr[1]].call(.....)
```

arr[0] will be "local"
arr[1] will be "process"
so window["local"]["process"] will refer to correct function.

Comment: Which is exactly as I suspected was happening, and your workaround may work for that instance, but how do I bind that automatically on page load, and from data-attributes? Also I won't know what actions will exist before, this is meant to be a jQuery library for unobtrusive outside-of-form form submission to multiple ajax actions during with a single click... I can point you to the full source if you need more to help.

Comment: okay the other way can be to use eval function.....eval(event.data.model.actions[event.data.q]).call(this) will also do......But remember ideally you should nave a mapping mechanism from "local.process" string in html to local.process in js execution environment, ohterwise rest every thing is more or less a hack to deal with situation.....